# Where is the definition of the XLSX printerSettings.bin file format?

Tags: excel, documentation, file-format

I want to be able to parse the printer settings binary files that Excel saves inside xl\printerSettings\printerSettingsNN.bin inside the XLSX zip archive. Much searching for documentation avails little.

Is this a common format that I just don't recognize, or is it specific to Excel? Is anyone aware of where to find details on the format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to be a Windows device-specific structure, [DEVMODE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183565.aspx).

Tracked it down via http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrisrae/archive/2010/10/06/where-is-the-documentation-for-office-s-docx-xlsx-pptx-formats-part-2-office-2010.aspx, which links to [ECMA-376, Second Edition, Part 1 - Fundamentals And Markup Language reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-376,%20Second%20Edition,%20Part%201%20-%20Fundamentals%20And%20Markup%20Language%20Reference.zip) from www.ecma-international.org.

Except from the relevant §15.2.15 on page 160:

> An instance of this part type contains information about the
>   initialization and environment of a printer or a display device. The
>   layout of this information is application-defined.
>
> [*Note*: It is recommended that a Printer Settings Part contain well documented XML content for improved interoperability;
>   however, there is no requirement on the format of the content
>   contained in a Printer Settings Part. *end note*]
>
> [*Example*: An Office
>   Open XML producer on Windows might store the DEVMODE structure defined
>   here:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/gdi/prntspol_8nle.asp,
>   while an application on the Mac OS might choose to store the print
>   record defined
>   here:http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Printing/index.html. *end
>   example*]

(Even 5,568 page standards suffer link rot- see [DEVMODE structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183565.aspx).)

That means, in C# for example, you can make use of the PrinterSettings' [GetHdevmode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.sethdevmode.aspx) and [SetHdevmode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.gethdevmode.aspx) methods to interop with the structure.