# Apache poi: How to setting 'Print on Both Sides' and 'Print one Sided'?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a problem when clone new sheet.

Sheet 1 setting **'Print on Both Sides'** but after `workbook.cloneSheet(0)`, new sheet lost setting **'Print on Both Sides'** and belong to  **'Print one Sided'**. I can't set **'Print on Both Size'** for new sheet because don't find method to set this.

Do poi-apache `printSetup()` have support setting **'Print on Both Sides'** and **'Print one Sided'**?

If haven't how to setting this?

Comment: Whether a printer is able duplex printing depends on the printer hardware. So this is not a print setup like [PrintSetup](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/PrintSetup.html) but a **printer** setup. `Excel` is able storing printer setups in it's files. This is done in a binary `DEVMODEA structure` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139328/where-is-the-definition-of-the-xlsx-printersettings-bin-file-format/23139999#23139999). In `Office Open XML` it is stored in `/xl/printerSettings/printerSettings[N].bin`.

Comment: `Apache POI` is not able cloning that structure properly until now. And I doubt it should be cloned at all because it often leads to problems when `Excel` files are opened by users which do not have exactly the printer as the creator had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether a printer is able duplex printing depends on the printer hardware. So this is not a print setup like [PrintSetup](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/PrintSetup.html) but a printer setup. Excel is able storing printer setups in it's files. This is done in a binary `DEVMODEA` structure ([Where is the definition of the XLSX printerSettings.bin file format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139328/where-is-the-definition-of-the-xlsx-printersettings-bin-file-format/23139999#23139999)). In `Office Open XML` it is stored in `/xl/printerSettings/printerSettings[N].bin`.

`Apache POI` is not able cloning that structure properly until now. And I doubt it should be cloned at all because it often leads to problems when Excel files are opened by users which do not have exactly the printer as the creator had. But of course, this is only my opinion and at least for `Office Open XML` it can be done.

`Workbook.cloneSheet` does not even clone the `PrintSetup` until now (current version `apache poi 4.1.2`). So we need at first cloning the  `PrintSetup`. The following code provides a method for cloning the `PrintSetup` from `Sheet source` to `Sheet clone`. It uses `java.beans.*` and `java.lang.reflect.Method` to get all values using getters from `sourcePrintSetup` and set those values to `clonePrintSetup` using the appropriate setters. It works only for getters without parameters and setters having exact one parameter. But this will be sufficient for `PrintSetup`.

Having the `PrintSetup` cloned, we can correct the cloned references from `XSSFSheet` to `/xl/printerSettings/printerSettings[N].bin`. `Workbook.cloneSheet` simply copies the relation to the old `/xl/printerSettings/printerSettings[N].bin` package part. This is wrong. The `/xl/printerSettings/printerSettings[N].bin` package part also needs to be cloned and the the cloned sheet needs to reference that new `/xl/printerSettings/printerSettings[N].bin` package part . This is done by method `repairCloningPrinterSettings` in following code.  This works using current `apache poi 4.1.2`. It must be changed when `Workbook.cloneSheet` changes in later versions.

The following code also  provides a method for binary cloning a `PackagePart`. It works only for part names which ends with `Idx` followed by dot followed by extension, for example `name1.xml` or `name1.png` or `printerSettings1.bin`. It counts up the `Idx` while cloning.

Complete Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ooxml.*;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.*;

import java.io.*;

import java.beans.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

class ExcelCloneSheet {

 //method to transfer InputStream to OutputStream
 //to work using Java 8 since InputStream.transferTo needs at least Java 9
 static void transferInputStreamToOutputStream(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws Exception {
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int bytesRead;
  while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
   out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
  }
 }

 //method for binary cloning a PackagePart
 //works only for part names which ends with Idx followed by dot followed by extension
 //throws Exception when not successful
 static PackagePart clonePackagePart(PackagePart sourcePart, String contentType) throws Exception {
  OPCPackage oPCPackage = sourcePart.getPackage();
  String sourcePartName = sourcePart.getPartName().getName();
  String destinationPartName = sourcePartName;
  String[] sourcePartNameSplitExtension = sourcePartName.split("\\.");
  if (sourcePartNameSplitExtension.length == 2) {
   sourcePartName = sourcePartNameSplitExtension[0];
   String sourcePartNameExtension = sourcePartNameSplitExtension[1];
   int i = sourcePartName.length();
   while (i > 0 && Character.isDigit(sourcePartName.charAt(i - 1))) {
    i--;
   }
   int idx = Integer.valueOf(sourcePartName.substring(i));
   idx++;
   destinationPartName = sourcePartName.substring(0, i) + idx + "." + sourcePartNameExtension;
  }
  PackagePartName partName = PackagingURIHelper.createPartName(destinationPartName);
  PackagePart destinationPart = oPCPackage.createPart(partName, contentType);
  InputStream in = sourcePart.getInputStream();
  OutputStream out = destinationPart.getOutputStream();
  //in.transferTo(out); // at least Java 9 needed
  transferInputStreamToOutputStream(in, out);
  out.close();
  return destinationPart;
 }

 //method for repairing the relation from sheet to "/xl/printerSettings/printerSettings[N].bin" package part
 //clones "/xl/printerSettings/printerSettings[N].bin" package part
 //repairs the wrong cloned relation to the old "/xl/printerSettings/printerSettings[N].bin" package part
 //works using apache poi 4.1.2
 //must be changed when Workbook.cloneSheet changes in later versions
 static void repairCloningPrinterSettings(XSSFSheet sheet) throws Exception {
  for (POIXMLDocumentPart.RelationPart relationPart : sheet.getRelationParts()) {
   String contentType = relationPart.getDocumentPart().getPackagePart().getContentType();
   if ("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.printerSettings".equals(contentType)) {
System.out.println(relationPart.getRelationship());
    //clone the "/xl/printerSettings/printerSettings[N].bin" package part
    PackagePart sourcePart = relationPart.getDocumentPart().getPackagePart(); 
    PackagePart destinationPart = clonePackagePart(sourcePart, contentType);
    //remove the wrong cloned relation to the old "/xl/printerSettings/printerSettings[N].bin" package part
    relationPart.getRelationship().getSource().removeRelationship(relationPart.getRelationship().getId());
    //add the relation to the new "/xl/printerSettings/printerSettings[N].bin" package part
    PackageRelationship relationship = sheet.getPackagePart().addRelationship(
     destinationPart.getPartName(), 
     TargetMode.INTERNAL, 
     XSSFRelation.PRINTER_SETTINGS.getRelation());
    //set Id of relation to the new "/xl/printerSettings/printerSettings[N].bin" package part 
    //in sheet's page setup
    if (sheet.getCTWorksheet().getPageSetup() == null) sheet.getCTWorksheet().addNewPageSetup();
    sheet.getCTWorksheet().getPageSetup().setId(relationship.getId());
   }
  }
 }

 //method for cloning the PrintSetup from Sheet source to Sheet clone
 //uses java.beans.* and java.lang.reflect.Method to get all values using getters from sourcePrintSetup
 //and set those values to clonePrintSetup using the appropriate setters
 //works only for getters without parameters and setters having exact one parameter
 //throws Exception when not successful
 static void clonePrintSetup(Sheet source, Sheet clone) throws Exception {
  PrintSetup sourcePrintSetup = source.getPrintSetup();
  PrintSetup clonePrintSetup = clone.getPrintSetup();
  for(PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : Introspector.getBeanInfo(PrintSetup.class).getPropertyDescriptors()) {
   Method getMethod = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod();
   Object value = null;
   if (getMethod != null && getMethod.getParameterTypes().length == 0) {
    value = getMethod.invoke(sourcePrintSetup);
    Method setMethod = propertyDescriptor.getWriteMethod();
    if (setMethod != null && setMethod.getParameterTypes().length == 1) {
     setMethod.invoke(clonePrintSetup, value);
System.out.println(setMethod + ": " + value);
    }
   }
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Workbook workbook  = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("Excel.xlsx"));

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  Sheet clone = workbook.cloneSheet(0);

  //Workbook.cloneSheet does not clone the PrintSetup. So we do it now.
  clonePrintSetup(sheet, clone);

  if (clone instanceof XSSFSheet) {
   XSSFSheet xssfSheet = (XSSFSheet)clone;
   //After cloning the cloned sheet has relation to the same 
   //"/xl/printerSettings/printerSettings[N].bin" package part as the source sheet had.
   //This is wrong. So we need to repair.
   repairCloningPrinterSettings(xssfSheet);
  }  

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("ExcelNew.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

After that code the cloned sheet in `ExcelNew.xlsx` should have same `PrintSetup` and also `printerSettings` as the source sheet.

Comment: Very useful. Thanks Axel!